# how to use uialert and uiactionsheet in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have a tableview of items and when i click one row, I want to use uialertview with uiactionsheet with button: edit, remove and cancel. When I click button edit, I will open a modal view. Before, I did edit modal view  already and when I click one row, I will go to edit modal view, but now I want to add uiactionsheet, so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write UIAlertview or UIActionsheet in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

I think it will be helpful to you.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"delete" otherButtonTitles:@"other 1", @"other 2", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

//or
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"button",@"button1", nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a UIAlertView as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", @"Remove", nil];
[alert show];
```

The following method will check which button is pressed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
         case 1:
         // perform Edit
             break;
         case 2:
         // perform Remove
             break;
         case 0:
         // perform Cancel, if any
             break;
    }
}
```